# line by line text data reading and performing simple calculation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, file-io

I have started working with Matlab recently. I only know basic matlab operations.So, i am struggling with the following problem. I would appreciate someone's kind help.

I have a text file in the format below whose record is expected to update each time according to the CoorsID. I need to take account of each row one after another (maintaing the CoorsID) and multiply the timed value with 10 for walk, 12 for urbanPuTLLLL,13 for urbanPuTDDDD and 14 for urbanPuTBus, then save in new matrices according to walk and other options until the sum of the Distance value become=18917.70763.

I did that bringing the dataset as a matrix in the matlab which was fairly easy. But, i cannot even figure out any clue to do this by line by line calcualtion. Advanced Thanks for your expert suggestion.

-saniul

```
###NumbersID    CoorsID Distance    Timed   Trailinformation###
###33   0   0   0   walk###
###33   1   1.881326228 0.152869117 walk####
###33   2   2.861352906 2.211478513 urbanPuTLLLL####
###33   3   2.894228468 2.381984857 urbanPuTLLLL####
###33   4   3.77420476  3.807208533 urbanPuTDDDD####
###33   5   3.893702709 3.911981757 urbanPuTDDDD####
###33   6   3.934894721 4.022707315 urbanPuTBus####
###33   7   4.230054787 4.131792708 urbanPuTBus####
```

Comment: If you've already solved the problem of reading your text file into a matrix, why don't you show us the matrix and explain the problem you still face in terms of that matrix ?  What relevance does the text file have to your problem ?  And show us the Matlab code you've already written.

Answer (score 0):

First I put the data you show in your question in to a file I named `test.m`.  Then this code reads it in to Matlab:

```
fid = fopen('test.m','r');

L=fgetl(fid); % gets first line "header"
L=fgetl(fid); % gets first data line
I=1;

while ~isnumeric(L) && L(1)~=-1 % fgetl(fid) returns -1 at end of file
    A(I,1:5) = textscan(L,'###%d %d %f %f %[^#]');
    L = fgetl(fid);
    I=I+1;
end
```

Use `doc fgetl` to open a help window to read about `fgetl`, and you can then read about the other commands.

A is a cell array with all the values converted in it.  Do `doc cell` to read about these.

Look in the `doc` for `textscan` to read about the input formatting I did.  `###%d` meant "skip three # then convert the rest to an integer."  `%[^#]` meant "read everything EXCEPT #."

From there, you can access the different elements of A, so `A{3,4}` is the number stored in the 3rd row, 4th column of the cell array named `A`, it is `2.211478513`

You go ahead and figure out how to do the multiplies and the addressing and the decisions when to stop adding things.

Comment: @Sani upvote useful answers, don't comment that they are useful.